# Mysterious error message on XFCE startup

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, startup

On an Xubuntu 22.04 freshly installed, I got this error message when the XFCE desktop starts, just after a successful login:

[image: error message]

I don't even know how to start to debug this message.
I looked at `~/.xsession-errors` and `/var/log/syslog` but there are lots of error messages and I don't know which one is the cause of this graphical error message.

Hints:

- I do not have the same error message with another graphical environment (such as Mate).
- I had a similar issue (maybe the same?) on my Ubuntu 20.04 with XFCE before I format to install Xubuntu 22.04, so maybe it is related to my XFCE customization (1 panel with menu, windows buttons, status indicators, and time - Microsoft style), or to my hardware?

Where should I look? Is it an issue from XFCE or from the system itself which is reported by XFCE?

Comment: `sudo ls /var/crash`

Comment: Thanks HolyBlackCat, I was not aware of this directory. There is only one file on this directory, called `_usr_share_apport_apport.0.crash`, and here is his content: https://pastebin.com/EZUipMTU
But the date of the crash is 9 days ago, so maybe it is not the cause of the error message?